# JSON API for PyPi - how to list packages?

Tags: json, api, pypi

There is a [JSON API for PyPI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON) which allows getting data for packages:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package_name>/json
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package_name>/<version>/json
```

However, is it possible to get a list of all PyPI packages (or, for example, recent ones) with a GET call?

Comment: Is [Index of Packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=index) the webpage you are looking for?

Comment: @vaibhaw No, it's not json. It has the data I need, but has some overhead for getting and parsing it.

Comment: True, it's not json. I thought you were looking for a list of all packages.

Comment: Any way to *search* PyPI by a package prefix or fragment (e.g. `lxm` -> lxml, lxml-wrapper, ...) via the simple / JSON APIs? The XML-RPC API offers a search, but apparently it is being deprecated :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [simple index at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/simple/) which lists all packages without overhead. You can then request the JSON of each package individually by performing a GET request to the URLs mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks! (Before I was parsing [Index of Packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=index), with its overhead for data transfer.)

Answer (score 17):

I know that you asked for a way to do this from the JSON API, but you can use the [XML-RPC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc) api to get this info very easily, without having to parse HTML.

```
try:
     import xmlrpclib
except ImportError:
     import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://pypi.python.org/pypi')
# get a list of package names
packages = client.list_packages()
```

Comment: Since [2017-04](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc?action=diff&rev1=43&rev2=44), the top of that page says: *The XMLRPC interface for PyPI is considered legacy and should not be used.*.

Comment: This worked for me - python version 3.6.6 - Date 1/17/2019.

Comment: For package releases you can use - client.package_releases

Comment: As of a few days ago this mode has been disabled by pypi.org

Comment: This still seems to be working as of 5/11/2021.

Comment: slow. 4x slower than `https://pypi.org/simple/`

Answer (score 8):

As of [PEP 691](https://peps.python.org/pep-0691/), you can now grab this through the Simple API if you request a JSON response.

```
curl --header 'Accept: application/vnd.pypi.simple.v1+json' https://pypi.org/simple/ | jq
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787985/8283848), but it's not working on `Python 3.6`
I found one solution with HTML parsing by using [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) package, But you have to install it via pip command as

```
pip install lxml
```

Then, try the following snippet

```
from lxml import html
import requests

response = requests.get("https://pypi.org/simple/")

tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

package_list = [package for package in tree.xpath('//a/text()')]
```

Comment: I would rather use [defusedxml](https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/) for externally-fetched XML files

Comment: @AlexanderShishenko How would you do that?

Comment: i would rather use `for match in re.finditer(r'"/simple/([^/]+)/"', html)` to parse this simple html

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: To make tasks like this simple I've implemented an own Python module. It can be installed using `pip`:

```
pip install jk_pypiorgapi
```

The module is very simple to use. After instantiating an object representing the API interface you can make use of it:

```py
import jk_pypiorgapi

api = jk_pypiorgapi.PyPiOrgAPI()
n = len(api.listAllPackages())
print("Number of packages on pypi.org:", n)
```

This module also provides capabilities for downloading information about specific packages as provided by `pypi.org`:

```py
import jk_pypiorgapi
import jk_json

api = jk_pypiorgapi.PyPiOrgAPI()
jData = api.getPackageInfoJSON("jk_pypiorgapi")
jk_json.prettyPrint(jData)
```

This feature might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to install some undeclared dependencies to get it working:  `pypine`, `jk_cmdoutputparsinghelper`, `invoke`, `jk_version`. I took a look at your pretty printer as well. Very nice!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will provide an update soon. BTW: PyPine is a new project I'm working on right now: A build and data processing framework in Python that will be open source soon. But jk_pyppiorgapi should not have a dependency for that. I'll look into that soon. If you encounter any issues, please file a bug report on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: @RogerDahl Fixed. You might want to update. However, I'm a bit confused: There should be no requirement for jk_cmdoutputparsinghelper and jk_version as both modules are not used by jk_pypiorgapi. If you want to help please check this again after installing the update and if this dependency still exists please file a bug report on the GitHub repo page. Thank you!

Comment: Just do a fresh venv, install `jk_pypiorgapi`, and try the snippets. You should get the missing deps that I did. A was actually trying to find a way to query PyPI for dependency information, and later found out that the information is not exposed by the current PyPI API.

Comment: @RogerDahl: It's not that easy as you think. As I am building system tools as well I've installed many self written packages on system level. I need to wipe half of the system to test this. Therefore I had just a look at all packages directly: In this case there are not that much files, so this is quite easy, and I eliminated the dependency to pypine. The other dependencies should not be used anyway, neither by jk_pipyorgapi, nor by its dependencies. However, I will set up a special testing machine soon to eliminate any future inconveniences regarding dependencies.

Comment: You should avoid modifing your system Python -- it's  very fragile and causes the type of problems you mentioned. Check out pyenv -- it's a wonderful tool that gives you full control over your Python environments.

Comment: using `https://pypi.org/simple/` under the hood ([source](https://github.com/jkpubsrc/python-module-jk-pypiorgapi/blob/master/src/jk_pypiorgapi/PyPiOrgAPI.py))

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible entirely within `requests`.  The requested content type (the mime type for JSON) just needs to go into the dictionary of headers.  `requests' can even decode the json into another dict for you:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://pypi.org/pypi/{package_name}/json', headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'});

info = r.json()['info']
print(f"requested package name = {package_name}, stored name: {info['name']}, author: {info['author']}, version: {info['version']}, license: {info['license']}")
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's Bash one-liner:

```sh
curl -sG -H 'Host: pypi.org' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://pypi.org/pypi/numpy/json | awk -F "description\":\"" '{ print $2 }' |cut -d ',' -f 1

# NumPy is a general-purpose array-processing package designed to...
```