# error using pip search (pip search stopped working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

[image: Error image]

I am getting this error in pip search while studying python.
The picture is an error when I pip search. Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
$ pip search pdbx
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 224, in _main                                                
    status = self.run(options, args)                                                                                                                                                
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 62, in run                                                    
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)                                                                                                                                         
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 82, in search                                                 
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__                                                                                                                
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request                                                                                                               
    verbose=self.__verbose                                                                                                                                                          
  File "*/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/xmlrpc.py", line 46, in request                                                 
    return self.parse_response(response.raw)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1342, in parse_response                                                                                                          
    return u.close()                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 656, in close                                                                                                                    
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])                                                                                                                                                   
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32500: 'RuntimeError: This API has been temporarily disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. Please use the Simple or JSON API instead.'>
```

Comment: You might want to use the same version of python you're studying with

Comment: In short, there's nothing to fix here. As the message says, search api is "temporarily" disabled

Comment: got the sameerror message pip 23.3 python3 try using https://pypi.org/project/pypi-simple/

Comment: this is also really disturbing my work,
I was using this function before without problems.
I am on a regular updated ubuntu 20.04 system using python3.8 intensively.
is there an alternative for the cli search?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/kd9qm3/is_pip_going_away_i_got_an_error_saying_pip_is/

Comment: See here how to use json api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419009/json-api-for-pypi-how-to-list-packages

Comment: or here https://opensource.com/article/21/3/python-package-index-json-apis-requests

Comment: Looks like the API has been disabled permanently now.

Answer (score 62):

The pip search command queries PyPI's servers, and PyPI's maintainers have explained that the API endpoint that the pip search command queries is very resource intensive and too expensive for them to always keep open to the public.  Consequently they sometimes throttle access and are actually planning to remove it completely soon.

See this [GitHub issues thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216) ...

The solution I am using for now is to `pip install pip-search` (a utility created by GitHub user @victorgarric).

So, instead of 'pip search', I use pip_search. Definitely beats searching PyPI via a web browser

Comment: Looks like `pip_search` has been removed - which is a good thing, as it scrapes the website, which just creates another problem for PyPI.

Comment: Nope, still there ... package name is [pip-search](https://pypi.org/project/pip-search/), but the command it provides is pip_search.  Haven't had time to look closely at what it does, but I sure appreciated that when I needed to search through some packages.  So I hope they don't remove it.

Comment: Ah, you're right, the package is still there on PyPI, it's just been removed/hidden from the author's GitHub.

Comment: @drkvogel Hmm... people do need to search for packages somehow. Whether they do it from the command line or in a browser, they are still placing load on a server somewhere. I imagine the command line program could be more "polite".

Comment: Hmm... is there are replacement for `pip show` as well.

Comment: @AttRigh Yes, tbh I never use `pip search` or anything like that. Google is plenty sufficient...

Comment: PyPI is currently showing https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search as the upstream repository for pip-search.

Answer (score 20):

Follow the suggestion from JRK at the discussion at github (last comment) the search command is temporarily disabled, use your browser to search for packages meanwhile:
Check the thread on [github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9292#issuecomment-747607182) and give him a thumb up ;)

Comment: This issue is more than temporary (see : https://status.python.org/ ).
Basically, they are experiencing a DDoS attack and they will be permanently disabling XMLRPC search.

Comment: Almost three years latter and the "Temporary" doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: Well `pip search` has been deprecated. I cannot guess why the command is still available in current and new `pip` versions. However it returns an error with a link to the deprecation note

Answer (score -2):

search on website, https://pypi.org/,
then install the package you wanted

Answer (score -3):

The error says

Please use the Simple or JSON API instead

You can try pypi-simple to query the pip repository

https://pypi.org/project/pypi-simple/

It gives an example too, I tried to use it here:

[pypi-simple version 0.8.0 DistributionPackage' object has no attribute 'get_digest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324724/pypi-simple-version-0-8-0-distributionpackage-object-has-no-attribute-get-dige):

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Nov  11 17:40:03 2020

@author: Pietro

"""


from pypi_simple import PyPISimple

def simple():
    package=input('\npackage to be checked ')
    
    try:
        with PyPISimple() as client:
            requests_page = client.get_project_page(package)
    
    except:
        print("\n SOMETHING WENT WRONG !!!!! \n\n",
        "CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION OR DON'T KNOW WHAT HAPPENED !!!\n")
        
    pkg = requests_page.packages[0]
    
    print(pkg)
    print(type(pkg))
    
    print('\n',pkg,'\n')

    print('\n'+pkg.filename+'\n')
    
    print('\n'+pkg.url+'\n')
    
    print('\n'+pkg.project+'\n')
    
    print('\n'+pkg.version+'\n')
    
    print('\n'+pkg.package_type+'\n')
    
    #print('\n'+pkg.get_digest()+'\n','ENDs HERE !!!!') #wasnt working
     

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  
   simple()
```

got -4 so far for this answer don't know why , figureout I can try to check for a package with:

```
# package_name = input('insert package name  :  ')

package_name = 'numpy'

import requests
url = ('https://pypi.org/pypi/'+package_name+'/json')
r = requests.get(url)


try: 
    data = r.json()
    
    for i in data:
        if i == 'info':
            print('ok')
            for j in data[i]:
                if j == 'name':
                    print((data[i])[j])
                    print([k for k in (data['releases'])])


    
except:
    print('something went south !!!!!!!!!!')
```