# runtime errors from pip(3) Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pip

I have a new Ubuntu 20.04 system and when I try to use pip I get:

```
rful011@secmgrtst01:~$ pip3 search elastalert
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.
```

I tried to upgrade to the latest pip version `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` but it made no difference.

I am baffled as to what to try next!

I have tried searching and there are lots of posts relating to runtime errors with pip i did not find anything relevant to my proble,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+search+RuntimeError%3A+PyPI%27s+XMLRPC+API+is+currently+disabled+due+to+unmanageable+load+and+will+be+deprecated+in+the+near+future.+See+https%3A%2F%2Fstatus.python.org%2F+for+more+information

Answer (score 2):

pip search is resource intensive so that is not available anymore as maintainers of [pypi decided that](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216). Also if you need more info, can check [here](https://status.python.org/incidents/grk0k7sz6zkp) as well. So as an alternative, you can use [pip-search](https://pypi.org/project/pip-search/) as that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365449/16983493). (I have not used that before though. So can not say how that performs.)